# CodeName One about lists

Tags: lwuit-list

I have a problem I want to use the list and when I click on a component of the list it take me to another form (make an action) meaning if I click on an item from the list depending on the selected index it takes me to another form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in a GUI builder app or manual app?

For GUI builder use the action event callback for the list see: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html

Then get the index/selected item using:

```
int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
Object value = list.getSelectedItem();
```

Then you can show the form you want using:

```
showForm("FormName", null);
```

In handcoded apps you can get the selected item/index in exactly the same way then do something like:

```
form.show();
```

To show a specific form.

Comment: Thank you shai and sorry for all these question i just started devlopping using LWUIT and CODENAme One ; i wanted to work with Code NAme one but there was a problem for me when am trying to call a php script using HttpConnexion and parse the xml using SAXParser wich made me go back to LWUIT. if you have any idea how to use the SAXPArser in COdeNAme One please tell me thank you.

Comment: Codename One has a builtin XMLParser class, LWUIT didn't have a SAXParser class.